# has the twitter api resource url for update status changed

Tags: twitter

Custom twitter app all of sudden stopped updating status and I'm new to Twitter.

```
<errors>
  <error code="34">Sorry, that page does not exist</error>
</errors>
Stack Trace:
   at TwitterOAuth.WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
```

Custom app is using the following resource url:

```
"https://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml"
```

Found a Code Project example that uses the following resource url and it worked for me:

```
"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net

---

So I tried

```
"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml"
```

Got the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an erro
r: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

now, twitter published new API V1.1
and the old API v1.0 will be retired on March 5th, 2013.
so you should review API V1.1

Comment: Thanks, found in API docs that XML and RSS are being discontinued.